# Exception when trying to delete a directory in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I get the following exception when I try to delete a directory in Isolated Storage in Windows Phone 7:

An error occurred while accessing IsolatedStorage.
there is no inner exception.

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    isf.DeleteDirectory(dir.TrimEnd('/'));
}
```

Notes:

1. putting it in a try-catch will hide the exception but still directory is not deleted!
2. before calling this I delete all files inside that using DeleteFile() so the problem can not be related to existing files inside the directory.
3. trimming the directory name is to make sure it's a valid directory name.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Any details in the (Inner) Exception? Are you 100% sure that `dir.TrimEnd('/')` yields a valid directory name?

Comment: there is no inner exception and trimming is to make sure dir is a valid directory name

Comment: 100% sure requires using IsolatedStorageFile.DirectoryExists()

Comment: I am reading directory names using .GetDirectoryNames. Is it sure enough? :P

Comment: Not as sure as Exists. Why the Trim? It changes the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, problem was that files were not being deleted correctly. The reason I was confused is that IsolatedStorageFile class does not warn you when you are deleting an invalid file. here is the correct code and some notes:

```
public static void DeleteDirectoryRecursive(this IsolatedStorageFile isf, string dir)
{
    foreach (var file in isf.GetFileNames(dir))
    {
        isf.DeleteFile(dir + file);
    }

    foreach (var subdir in isf.GetDirectoryNames(dir))
    {
        isf.DeleteDirectoryRecursive(dir + subdir + "\\");
    }

    isf.DeleteDirectory(dir.TrimEnd('\\'));
}
```

Notes:

1. there is no difference between '\' and '/' in file paths
2. trimEnd() is required when DeleteDirectory otherwise exception "path must be a valid file name" is thrown.
3. GetFileNames() and GetDirectoryNames() return only the name part not the full path. so in order to use each result you need to combine it with the directory (DeleteFile() in this example)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code and your description, you would be recreating the IsolatedStorageFile access on every iteration?

You should post all the code, since the error isn't related to what you told so far. As for a working example, see [this blog post](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/11/isolated-storage-for-windows-phone-7/). If that fails with your directory name, you're clearly doing something wrong.

Also, I believe it uses backslashes, not forward-slashes for paths, so your Trim() would be rather useless either way.

Comment: (1) backslash and forward slash are treated the same in file paths in any of windows operating systems. (2) without trimming I get "path must be a valid file name"

Answer (score 1):

```
    `public static void DeleteDirectoryRecursive(string directory, IsolatedStorageFile store)
    {
        if (!store.DirectoryExists(directory))
            return;
        var pattern = Path.Combine(directory, "*");
        foreach (var file in store.GetFileNames(pattern))
        {
            store.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(directory, file));
        }
        foreach (var folder in store.GetDirectoryNames(pattern))
        {
             DeleteDirectoryRecursive(Path.Combine(directory, folder), store);
        }

        store.DeleteDirectory(directory);
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to valipour, I solved the problem

```
foreach (var file in isf.GetFileNames(dir))
{
    isf.DeleteFile(dir + file);
}
```

In my case the variable dir is "images". In order to get all file names in "images" directory, you should use `isf.GetFileNames("images/*")`

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed Valipour's version and make it work. Added some checks to improve stability + fixed some names. This works for me on Lumia 920.

```
private void DeleteDirectoryRecursive(string dir)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir)) return;

        try
        {
            using (var isoFiles = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                foreach (var file in isoFiles.GetFileNames(dir + "\\*"))
                {
                    var filename = dir + "/" + file;
                    if (isoFiles.FileExists(filename))
                        isoFiles.DeleteFile(filename);
                }

                foreach (var subdir in isoFiles.GetDirectoryNames(dir))
                {
                    var dirname = dir + subdir + "\\";
                    if (isoFiles.DirectoryExists(dirname))
                        DeleteDirectoryRecursive(dirname);
                }

                var currentDirname = dir.TrimEnd('\\');
                if (isoFiles.DirectoryExists(currentDirname))
                    isoFiles.DeleteDirectory(currentDirname);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```