# Having problems deleting all files in a directory, then the directory itself

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, directory, isolatedstorage

I am trying to delete a directory & all it's contents when I tap on a ContextMenu's MenuItem. However I seem to be running into to issues, as the files/directory aren't being deleted.

However I am not running into any errors, it just doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void gridSessionDelete_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).Owner as Grid);
    var title = (TextBlock)item.FindName("Title");
    string directory = title.Text;

    var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    string[] fileList = appStorage.GetFileNames(directory + "\\*");

    foreach (string file in fileList) 
    { 
        appStorage.DeleteFile(directory + "\\" + file); 
    }

    appStorage.DeleteDirectory(directory);

    bindList();
}
```

does anyone have any help on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks all help is appreciated!

Comment: This thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801766/exception-when-trying-to-delete-a-directory-in-isolated-storage

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to shed much light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see a couple of places, where the error could be.

First, this line:

```
var item = (((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).Owner as Grid);
```

As you know, when you cast types with **as** keyword, the result might be null and no exception is thrown.

Second, and IMO most important:

This line:

```
string[] fileList = appStorage.GetFileNames(directory + "\\*");
```

That won't find anything. You should use "*.*" (star-point-star)  instead of "*"(star) in search request.

Also, when you work with IsolatedStorage, use **using** keyword, like:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
              // your code
            }
```

Comment: Eh, does anyone know, how to write expression like *.*(star-point-star) in answer? It looks like italic text after formating.

Comment: In previous code I have used in the project the `string[] fileList = appStorage.GetFileNames(directory + "\\*")` returns results. So I don't see why it shouldn't work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code actually execute? Do breakpoints get hit? If so here is code that I use to delete all files in a directory. It does work for me. The main difference I see is in the DeleteFile method.

```
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (storage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
{
    foreach (var oldFile in storage.GetFileNames(string.Concat(directoryName, "\\*")))
    {
        storage.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(directoryName, oldFile));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using System.IO.Path.Combine, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Rather embarrassingly I have realised it was because I was using the `_Tap` event, not the `_Click` event. For some reason the `ContextMenu` didn't trigger the Tap hahaaa

Comment: I should have said on the comment above, my code worked fine in the end